# Atlas and Globe shows my country not

Tags: relays, atlas

I want to see my **country** (Austria) with Globe and Atlas!
What can I do?

Comment: What is "your country"?

Comment: My country is Austria

Comment: You should be on  https://atlas.torproject.org and on https://globe.torproject.org/  see your country. But you can't see my country Austria, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/) you can use the search term `country:at` to see only relays from Austria. However if there are more than 40 results Atlas won't show you any results. So you need to refine your search. Example: Search for [Austrian relays with the additional term `ab`](https://atlas.torproject.org/#search/ab%20country:at).

[Globe](https://globe.torproject.org/) also allows you to look for a specific country. There is a scroll-down list on top of the page. You can look for [Austrian relays](https://globe.torproject.org/#/search/query=&filters[country]=at) and it will show you the first 50 results.